# SystemVerilog - How to get the number of enumerated types at compile time

Tags: enums, system-verilog

I trying to find a way to get the number of possible enumerations in an `enum` type at compile time. I need this for initializing a templated class that uses enumerated types.

I am curious if there is a utility function (or system task) that gives this. It would be similar to `$size()` but for enumerated types. However, I can't seem to find a function for that. After doing a lot of research, it doesn't seem to be possible.

Here is an example I am trying to do:

```
typedef enum {RANDOM, STICKY, SWEEP} bias_t;

// can be parameterized to pick another enum type at random
class enum_picker #(type T = bias_t); //type must be an enumerated type
    local T current_type;
    local const int weights[$size(T)]; //<--- How do I get the number of enumerated types?

    function T pick_type();
        ... some code ...
    endfunction
endclass
```

So for the variable `weights`, it is an array of weights in which its size is the number of enumerated types. Right now it is `32` because of the `$size()` call but that is wrong; in this particular code example, the array size should be `3`.

Is there a way to do this? Or is this simply not allowed in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to set up `weights` as a `const`; you would not be able to set values into it. You can use the `num()` method to get the number of enumerations.

```
class enum_picker #(type T = bias_t); //type must be an enumerated type
  local T current_type;
  local int weights[]; 
  function new;
    weights = new[current_type.num()];
    foreach (weights[i]) weights[i] = $urandom_range(10);
  endfunction

    function T pick_type();
       
    endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: A quick followup question: Wouldn't it be better if you used `current_type.num()` instead of `last()` method in case the variable is enumerated in a different way (i.e. one-hot enumeration)?

Comment: @VarunGovind, yes, forgot about that method. Much better